# Application Error in Heroku Node.js App

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have [MVA Downloader](https://github.com/wankycoder/mva-downloader/) repo,It's Heroku page which is showing application error. How can I fix this?[Heroku Link](http://mva-downloader.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Please find the actual error : you should run heroku logs to get logging output.
& 
Please try to use port like :
http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on', http.address().port);
});

Comment: In Heroku, it's showing build succeeded but in Travis, i get [this](https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/153947526/log.txt?deansi=true) error. And I can't figure out where it's missing a ')'